# A signal that can be transformed by Fourier transform and its frequency

Tags: signal, fourier

A signal A, which is in time domain, can be transformed by Fourier transform into its frequency contents.

Then, is the signal A's frequency the highest frequency part of its Fourier transform? (i.e. is the signal itself oscillating at the frequency of its highest Fourier transform frequency part?)

Comment: You asking: what is the frequency of the signal ? Or what is the frequency of spectrum of signal ? Or what is frequency of signal with particular spectrum ? Broadly, you are trying to apply single charateristic to object with multiples of same charateristics. Try use the wording like "average" or "maximum", then you will get better question

Comment: We need further information from you on this question. Are there a specific subset of signals you are thinking about or any possible signal? Please try to answer @RocketSurgeon also.

Answer (score 5):

Like *The Photon* says, it's the lowest non-zero frequency, it's called the fundamental, and the other harmonics are integer multiples of it. That means the fundamental is the frequency with the longest period in the signal.

[image]

This AM signal is the product of two frequencies, a low baseband signal frequency and a higher modulating frequency, which in this case is exactly 10 times the baseband frequency. The signal's period is the lower frequency's period, and its inverse is the fundamental's frequency.
The function is (3 + sin(\$\omega_0\$)) \$\times\$ sin(\$\omega_m\$). Since

\$ sin(x) \times sin(y) = \dfrac{cos(x – y) – cos (x + y)}{2}\$

we have

\$ V_t = 3 \cdot sin(\omega_m t) + \dfrac{cos(\omega_m t - \omega_0 t)}{2} - \dfrac{cos(\omega_m t + \omega_0 t)}{2} \$

and, with \$\omega_m\$ = 10 \$\times\$ \$\omega_0\$

\$ V_t = 3 \cdot sin(10 \cdot \omega_0 t) + \dfrac{cos(9 \cdot \omega_0 t)}{2} - \dfrac{cos(11 \cdot \omega_0 t)}{2} \$

which can be written in the standard Fourier series form:

\$ V_t = -\dfrac{1}{2}sin(9 \cdot \omega_0 t - \dfrac{\pi}{2}) + 3 \mbox{ } sin(10 \cdot \omega_0 t) + \dfrac{1}{2}sin(11 \cdot \omega_0 t - \dfrac{\pi}{2}) \$

For a repeating signal the frequency of the fundamental is greater than zero, and the harmonics show in the spectrum as equal-spaced lines.
For a non-repeating signal the limit of the signal's period goes to \$\infty\$ so that the frequency of the fundamental goes to \$ \displaystyle \lim_{f \to 0} \$, and the series of harmonics forms a continuous spectrum.

I made the following observation in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/32453/2064):

> "Sometimes it's difficult to see the fundamental sine in it. Take for instance the sum of a 3Hz sine and a 4Hz sine. The resulting waveform will repeat once every second, that's 1Hz. The 1Hz is the fundamental, even if its amplitude is zero. The series can be written as
>
> \$ V_t = 0 \cdot sin(\omega_0 t) + 0 \cdot sin(2 \omega_0 t) + sin(3 \omega_0 t) + sin(4 \omega_0 t)\$
>
> All the following terms also have zero amplitude.

Why is the fundamental frequency 1Hz,and not 0.5Hz, for instance? 3Hz and 4Hz are also multiples of that. The fundamental is the **greatest common divider** of the composing harmonics, and the GCD of 3 and 4 is 1. If you would choose a lower frequency its period will show a repetition of the signal, twice in the case of 0.5Hz.

> A note on GCD
> It has been suggested that GCD only applies to integers, like in the given example. GCD can also be applied to the rationals, however. I found that the definition \$ GCD\left(\dfrac{a}{b}, \dfrac{c}{d} \right) = \dfrac{GCD(a\cdot d, c \cdot b)}{b \cdot d} \$ seems to work, and has been confirmed to be the correct method.

Note that also in the AM example the amplitude of the fundamental is zero. The modulated signal only consists of the 9th, 10th and 11th harmonic. GCD(9 \$\omega_0\$, 10 \$\omega_0\$, 11 \$\omega_0\$) = \$\omega_0\$.

Comment: I downvoted :) Fourier transform is specifically made for non-periodic signals, while Fourier series are for periodic ones. The spectrum can be an arbitrary function, as well as the signal in the time domain. And periodic in one domain means discrete in the other, and vice versa, while the signal can easily be none of them.

Comment: @clabacchio - I still don't know what's wrong in my answer.

Comment: I may have misread it, in that case I'll revert and apologize, but I understand that it's about harmonics and multiple frequencies, while the question is about Fourier transform (I assume OP has the same concept), which in my experience is for non-periodic signals, then doesn't produce harmonics but something like the [first row](http://gmrt.ncra.tifr.res.in/gmrt_hpage/Users/doc/WEBLF/LFRA/img845.gif)

Comment: Really, nothing personal, but I was trying to push the asnwers I like more to the top. I've upvoted you so many times, you can forgive me :)

Comment: @clabacchio - OP asks about "the signal's frequency" and "the highest frequency part". Those hint at discrete values, and my guess was that OP meant series where he said transform. To me this absolutely points to the concept of fundamental frequency (and harmonics).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3583/discussion-between-clabacchio-and-stevenvh)

Comment: This whole thing hints at a poorly defined question.

Answer (score 4):

The Fourier transform gives, like you said, the "frequency contents" of the signal. The signal has content at *all* of the frequencies where the transform is non-zero.

If the original signal is periodic, it's Fourier transform will have characteristic spikes or peaks at the oscillation frequency of the signal and its harmonics. For example, if the signal is repetitive with frequency *f*, the Fourier transform will have peaks at *f*, 2**f*, 3**f*, etc. Depending on the nature of the signal, some of these peaks could be missing (for example, a pure sine wave will just show the fundamental frequency, a square wave will only have odd harmonics, etc.)

So for a periodic signal you might say that the oscillation frequency of the signal is the *lowest* frequency of the Fourier transform, not the highest.

**Edit:** As Stevenvh and Teleclavo point out, it's possible that the missing peaks include the fundamental. It's even possible for there to be many many missing peaks below the first one observed in the spectrum. For example, take a 1 Hz square wave with extremely fast rising edges (say 10 ps). Now apply a high-pass filter with cut-off at 1 GHz. Depending on how sharp is the filter, you might see no output below 10 MHz and a series of peaks at 1 Hz intervals from there up to 10 GHz, meaning the first 10 million harmonics are absent. but the repetition period remains 1 s.

And its also possible to have an aperiodic signal that has a spectrum composed of multiple peaks. My answer relates to cases where you have independent information that tells you the signal is periodic.

Comment: The oscillation frequency is at the frequency of every frequency it is oscillating at would be more correct to me. The fact we are having a large number of users arguing adamantly about this is a sign that we are trying to define a quantity that cannot be defined, you make the point of specifying to look at harmonics and such it must be period and I find your answer the best fit.

Answer (score 2):

No.  For instance the Fourier transform of a Gaussian pulse is another Gaussian pulse, neither of which appears to oscillate.

However, the opposite is true.  If a signal is a sinusoidal-like oscillator, then the FT or FFT will show a spike or peak.

Answer (score 2):

It is neither the lowest frequency component (of the Fourier transform) nor the highest. The Fourier transform exists even for non-periodic signals, and those signals (obviously) do not oscillate at any frequency.

I'll say even more. Even for periodic signals, it is still neither the lowest nor the highest frequency component, what -in general- determines its period. If you add two sinusoids of 19 kHz and 20 kHz (as it is commonly done in intermodulation tests for audio equipment), the spectrum has one delta at 19 kHz, and one delta at 20 kHz. However, the resulting signal has a period of 1 kHz. Neither 19 kHz, nor 20 kHz.

If you mention Fourier, forget that one signal may "oscillate" at only one frequency, and you try to see what determines the frequency of that oscillation. In general, a signal "oscillates" at infinite frequencies. All those frequencies which have nonzero component, at their Fourier transform.

---

**Added**: Even for a periodic signal, the fundamental frequency is not the one of the lowest frequency component (invisible or not) in the Fourier transform.

Take this simple example:

\$S(t)=1+sin(2\pi f_1·t)\$

with \$f_1=\$1 kHz, which looks like this:

[image: S(t)]

Notice that its period is 1 ms.

Now look at the Fourier transform, S(f), of S(t):

[image: S(f)]

What is the frequency of its lowest frequency component? Zero. Is f=0 the fundamental frequency of S(t)? No. The fundamental frequency of S(t) is 1 kHz.

Comment: @FedericoRusso But my answer is not different because of that. It is different because it clearly states that it is neither the lowest nor the highest, and that -in general- signals oscillate at infinite frequencies (if decomposed into sinusoids). It is misleading to say, as stevenh did, that a non-repeating signal has a fundamental frequency.

Comment: @FedericoRusso I know what you mean, and you know what I mean. The difference is that the *definition* is on my side. You show me a reputable reference that defines or even talks about the fundamental of a non-periodic signal. I can show you infinite, that define it for periodic signals: http://home.iitk.ac.in/~kundu/paper86.pdf  http://home.iitk.ac.in/~kundu/paper88.pdf ...

Comment: @FedericoRusso Hopefully the added example will put an end to this discussion.

Comment: @FedericoRusso You did not get the point of the example. This is not about limits at all. Tell me: 1) what's the fundamental frequency of S(t)? 2) The answer to 1) is coherent with what Steven's answer was? NO. // You've just seen that Steven corrected his answer (to leave it even more weird), because he has seen that I was saying something correct (unlike what he had, and still has). You've just seen this, but you will never upvote me, and I'd bet that you even upvoted him. That's the disappointing side of this page.

Comment: OP asks about "the signal's frequency", that's asking for an explanation about fundamental (definition) and harmonics (definition). I should downvote you for not answering OP's question.

Comment: @FedericoRusso. Sure. The fundamental frequency is only defined for periodic signals, and it is equal to the inverse of the period with which they repeat, in time. // The OP did NOT mention neither "fundamental" nor "harmonics", in his question. Why should I mention those? To tell him that a signal does not have, in general, "a frequency", but instead, infinite ones (the ones that show up in its transform)? // Downvote whoever you want. // You are starting to be tiresome, and no, there's nothing wrong with me.

Comment: @Telaclavo, It would be much better in my opinion to look at an example that did not include a DC offset. Using a frequency of 0 is a little silly, it would be the same as using a frequency of infinity, it is a special case. Can you recreate your example or add another with a non-zero frequency to explain your point.

Comment: @Kortuk A spectrum having nonzero amplitude at f=0 is not silly at all. Exactly that same S(t) I gave happens zillions of times, in real circuits. Testing an answer against such a common (and therefore valid) example is a perfectly valid method in engineering.

Comment: @Telaclavo, you may misunderstand me, it is a bad example of a lower frequency not forming the harmonic, DC has no frequency to it, it is the single point in all of the frequency domain that does not represent change/unit time in the signal. I think the root of all these arguments are a very poor question which is rooted in someone needing to learn more about frequency domain, but as an outside observer using 0Hertz to show that the lowest frequency is not necessarily affecting the fundamental is counter productive, 0hertz is the special case.

Comment: -1. The best thing you do is say what it's not (neither the lowest, nor the highest frequency), you don't come with a positive answer, backed by a reputable source. You've had enough time to fix this.

Comment: @FedericoRusso Yours is the most unfair, technically nonsense -1 I've seen here, to date. My first and third paragraphs *do* answer the OP. Read them. My 3rd paragraph tells him that a signal does not have -in general- "a frequency", but infinite ones. If you are waiting for me to tell him which one is that magic, (single) "signal A's frequency", I just can't. *No one can*. The question is wrong. And a reputable source that backs up what? That says how a Fourier transform is defined, and what it means? That's all you need, to check the validity of my answer.

Comment: I commented on it before, and that comment got 2 upvotes. And I'm no more strict here for you than you are regarding stevenvh's answer, where you stumbled over a missing word and dismissed the answer because of that.

Answer (score 0):

The dominant frequency of the signal A is the one you might call it. For example a piano with 3 strings will generate 3 similar frequencies plus many complex harmonics which are typically not monotonic  in strength with harmonic , not to mention phase.

So the audio of Note A0 on the piano also has harmonics of a lower magnitude on A1, A2, A3, A4 , A5, A7 and A8 and so on through all the octaves or multiples of f1 where the multiples are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 etc

If the fundamental is dominant you call its main frequency the lowest one. But if you mute the lowest frequency say on a guitar midwave on the string or 1/4 way up the string. You suppress the fundamental and thus an overtone or harmonic is dominant so you hear that the loudest and the Fourier content on a Spectral Density meter or "Spectrum Analyzer" will prove that.

I hope this non-mathematical approach is technical enough to satisfy your curiosity.