# DC level in Fourier series

Tags: fourier

From [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/32453/3920):

> The Fourier series:
>
> \$ V_t = \dfrac{a_0}{2} +    \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}[a_i sin(i \omega_0 t) + b_i cos(i \omega_0 t) ]  \$

Why is the DC level written as \$\dfrac{a_0}{2}\$, and not \$a_0\$? stevenvh says it's convention, but there has to be an explanation. Where does it come from?

Answer (score 6):

This stumped me for a while as well but it is actually quite simple.

**The general Fourier series:**

\$ g(x) = a_0 +  \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n sin(n x) + b_n cos(n x) ]  \$

I am not going to do all the math but if you use the orthogonal signal space \$ \left\{{1, cos(nx),sin(nx)}\right\} n\in N \$ you can derive the fourier series terms as:

\$ a_n = \dfrac{1}{\pi} \displaystyle \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} g(x)cos(n x)\,\mathrm{d}x\$

\$ b_n = \dfrac{1}{\pi} \displaystyle \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} g(x)sin(n x)\,\mathrm{d}x\$

And:

\$ a_0 = \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \displaystyle \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\$

**The "regular" Fourier series**

\$ g(x) = \dfrac{a_0}{2} +  \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n sin(n x) + b_n cos(n x)]\$

For the sake of symmetry the \$a_0\$ term was redefined as:

\$ a_0 = \dfrac{1}{\pi} \displaystyle \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\$

to be similar to \$a_n\$ and \$b_n\$. Therefore the \$\dfrac{1}{2}\$ term was added to the expression of the Fourier series.

**Reference:**

[Generalized Fourier Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFourierSeries.html)
[Fourier Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html)

Comment: Yes.  Just restating your answer: by making the constant term a0/2, the formula for an works for all n, including 0.

Answer (score 4):

That is one form the fourier series can be written. Another one is
$$V_t = \sum\limits_{i=-\infty}^\infty c_ie^{ji\omega t}$$
with the imaginary unit j.

When you apply Euler's formula \$e^{j\phi}=\cos\phi+j \sin\phi\$ you get the form you already know. The coefficients are \$a_i = c_i + c_{-i}\$, \$b_i = j(c_i + c_{-i})\$.

For the special case \$i = 0\$ you have now two options that looks feasible

1. Apply the formula \$a_i = c_i + c_{-i}\$ to be consistent with the cases \$i\neq0\$ and you get \$a_0 = 2 c_0\$
2. Define the coefficient \$a_0\$ so it doesn't relate to the other coefficents \$a_i\$.

What you choose seems to be a matter of taste.

Comment: No, I don't get the idea :(. I can imagine that you add \$c_{-1}\$ and \$c_{1}\$, but why would you add \$c_0\$ to itself?

Comment: @Federico Russo - I tried to clarify my answer.

Comment: That can't be right. It's not "\$\sum\limits_{i=-\infty}^\infty\$, *count zero twice*". (I don't know the right answer either.)

Comment: @stevenvh - Like you said in your the answer the op linked to it is a convention. IMO, \$a_0\$ could be anything e.g. \$a_0 = 11c_0\$. The case I listed at 1. follows the pattern given by the other coefficients. But isn't more wrong or right then the 2. case.

Comment: @stevenvh - Or the other way around: take the formula given by the op and the formula I have given. Now solve the relationship between the coefficients a and c. When you do the same with the formula given by the op but with \$a_0\$ instead of \$\frac{a_0}{2}\$ and the formula I have given, you get another relationship. But both are still right!

Answer (score 0):

Try another perspective to Pet's one.
 This is not formal and **may** be just wrong but it seems to work and make sense:

Deal with ai and sine terms. Same argument applies to bi and cos terms.

For any ith term with i > 0 if ai = 1 you get a sinusoid that extends from -1 to +1. ie
 Peak to peak magnitude of any sine term = 2ai.
 RMS magnitude of any single sine term is sqrt(2).ai
 Similarly for bi and cos terms.

If we apply the same convention for DC, for DC to have Vdc = a0 implies a DC peak to peak value of 2a0 (as is the case with ai sine terms).
 To maintain a consistent convention we set
 Vdc = 1/2.a0

The above arguably arises because an AC value is measured about its mean value =  about 0 and so implies that an equal and opposite peak value exists.
 For a sine wave it does.
 For DC it doesn't.
 We are trying to fit a single side signal in one case only into an otherwise bipolar system.

---

In this useful 28 page PDF [Introduction to the Fourier series](http://www.designers-guide.org/theory/fourier.pdf) ewuation (3) on page 4  uses a0 and not a0/2, thus differing from your example, and violating the consistent convention as mentioned above.

This [wikipedia page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Signals_and_Systems/Fourier_Series) follows your convention without comment.

See [2nd kjsingh123 post on this page](http://www.dutchforce.com/~eforum/index.php?s=525d6e3254bb360f735deafce0581c09&showtopic=22201) for a0 derivation

Comment: Sorry, Russell, but I'm not convinced by this one. A DC voltage of +2V doesn't have a peak-to-peak value of 4V. That's 2V, just like the peak value. CMIIW.

Comment: @Stevenh - read my lips :-) - or words. It's easy in things like this to hear things that are not intended.   Your 2V/4V comparison is my point. A DCV value which is p-p 2V is +/- 1V around it's mean. BUT unlike ALL other terms the mean is not midway between Vmax and Vmin but AT Vmin. The 0.5 factor allows us to treat a signal that is offset by +half its magnitude with the same convention as all the other terms. In fourier analysis 4Vp-p square wave IS a +/- 2V AC signal - ie it matches the non-rule that you quote. Only DC doesn't and it differs by the factor of 2 which is being discussed.

Comment: OK, I follow that, but your starting point is wrong IMO. The mean of a 2V DC signal is 2V DC, not 1V.